# How do i post multipart/form-data that contain symbol

Tags: linux, curl, multipartform-data

It made me have a headache for hours, i try to post image to twitpic with my twitter account using curl.

```
curl -F "username=myusername" -F "password=='hwsh[g" -F "message=test twitpic" -F media=@/dos/smallapps2/smallapps/tiny-delicious/snapshot/test.png http://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost
```

It alway return

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rsp stat="fail">
        <err code="1001" msg="Invalid twitter username or password" />
    </rsp>
```

But when i changed twitter password to simple word (not contain "=", "-","[") 
It OK

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp status="ok">
 <statusid>4084106555</statusid>
 <userid>33348202</userid>
 <mediaid>56qrz</mediaid>
 <mediaurl>http://twitpic.com/i6qwg</mediaurl>
</rsp>
```

My question is how to do this thing with strong password that contain any character.
Hint please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your example, with the exact same password (on a test account) and did not have any issues uploading my sample image.  I even looked through a pcap to make sure the encoding is being done correctly.

```
-desktop:~/Dropbox$ curl -vv -F "username=********" -F "password=='hwsh[g" -F "message=test twitpic" -F media=@./code_Quality_Measurement_wtfm.jpg  http://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost
* About to connect() to twitpic.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 174.36.58.233... connected
* Connected to twitpic.com (174.36.58.233) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/uploadAndPost HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.5 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: twitpic.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 46066
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------50b761e49108
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/0.6.35
< Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2009 19:06:38 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
< Content-Length: 196
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp status="ok">
 <statusid>6311967029</statusid>
 <userid>**********</userid>
 <mediaid>rzu6c</mediaid>
 <mediaurl>http://twitpic.com/rzu6c</mediaurl>
* Connection #0 to host twitpic.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
</rsp>
```

what Shell are you using?  depending on what "special" characters you use in your password, you may need to escape them differently to keep the shell from expanding/etc

any time you use double quotes in a command line, you have to deal with variable expansion, especially if your password contains a dollarsign ($).  it may be better to use single quotes around the password field, and explicitely escape any single quotes in your password:

```
-F 'password==\'hwsh[g'
```